# Is there any in canon date of whether the goblins existed before normal human Wizards or Witches?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there any in canon information at to whether the goblins existed before the Wizards and Witches or did human magic users exist before goblins?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the furthest history we have of the goblins is that Ragnuk the First forged The Sword of Gryffindor "a thousand years ago" for Godric Gryffindor. Thereofre, it would be unclear which came first.

> The sword of Gryffindor was made a thousand years ago by goblins, the magical world’s most skilled metalworkers, and is therefore enchanted. Fashioned from pure silver, it is inset with rubies, the stone that represents Gryffindor in the hour-glasses that count the house points at Hogwarts. Godric Gryffindor’s name is engraved just beneath the hilt.
>
> The sword was made to Godric Gryffindor’s specifications by Ragnuk the First, finest of the goblin silversmiths, and therefore King (in goblin culture, the ruler does not work less than the others, but more skillfully). When it was finished, Ragnuk coveted it so much that he pretended that Gryffindor had stolen it from him, and sent minions to steal it back. Gryffindor defended himself with his wand, but did not kill his attackers. Instead he sent them back to their king bewitched, to deliver the threat that if he ever tried to steal from Gryffindor again, Gryffindor would unsheathe the sword against them all.
>
> <sub>[Pottermore, Writing by J.K. Rowling, The Sword of Gryffindor](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-sword-of-gryffindor)</sub>