# Who was the first Wizard or Witch in the Harry Potter Universe?

Tags: harry-potter

Not sure if this has been asked previously, I couldn't find any references to it.  This question came to me based on this one - [Is there any in canon date of whether the goblins existed before normal human Wizards or Witches?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205820/is-there-any-in-canon-date-of-whether-the-goblins-existed-before-normal-human-wi) but who was the first wizard or witch in the Harry Potter universe?

We know from the books and movies that Olivander's has been making wands since 382BC, so there would of had to have been Wizards or Witches around before that, but has J K Rowling ever given any information as to when magic was first used?

Was magic always around in the Harry Potter universe?  If so when and who used it first?

**Edit -** 
I'm not sure that the linked question does actually answer mine.  JK Rowling might have stated that magic ability is gene related, and the answer speculating that this means the ability may of spontaneously erupted sometime in prehistory is just that, speculation.  The comment by NKCampell is actually what I'm asking.
If there is a magical progenitor (either a magical Adam or Eve) then is that mentioned in any myths/legends that Wizards or Witches have in their universe?

Comment: RE: Your edit for reopening. The answer to the duplicate is speculation because there is no canon (which that answer also states), so largely the same answer will apply to this question. Also, if a canon statement were to arise that there was a magical Adam/Eve then that would also answer both questions.

Comment: FWIW [Is there a “first” pureblood in the Harry Potter Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71714/98028) is dupe-closed with the same target, comments are worth looking into, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Jenayah - I'll leave this closed now